# data frame condition multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Say one has a data frame as follows:

```
data <- data.frame('obs' = c('a','c','b'), 'top1' = c('a','b','c'), 'top2' = c('b', 'c', 'f'), 'top3' = c('g', 'h', 'd'))
```

I wan to compute a new column `topn` which is a conditional that works in the following fashion: if the value of `obs` is in any of the `top` columns then `topn` should be equal to `obs`, otherwise `topn` can be assigned any value, say `top1`. Of course I know I can do this with an `or` and `ifelse`, but I'm looking for a shorter way to write it because in my table I can have up to 10 `top` columns.

```
 obs top1 top2 top3 topn
   a    a    b    g  a
   c    b    c    h  c
   b    c    f    d  c
```

Comment: this might be good if obs is the first column and all of the others are 'top' `data$topn = data[cbind(1:nrow(data),apply(data, 1, function(x) 1+!(x[1] %in% x[-1])))]
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looking for a vectorized approach, then we can use the `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` to find if there are any matches, then with `ifelse` get the column values based on the logical `vector`

```
i1 <- data[-1] == data['obs'][col(data[-1])]
data$topn <- ifelse(rowSums(i1) != 0, as.character(data$obs), as.character(data$top1))
data$topn
#[1] "a" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful and quick.

```
f=function(a){
```

`if(a[1] %in% a[-1]){`

```
    return (a[1])
  }
```

`else{sample(a[-1],1)}`

`}`

`data$topn=apply(data,1,f)`